# Why does x^y for unsigned shorts result in a signed int?

Tags: c++

I ran into an unexpected error today. When I was doing bit manipulations on unsigned shorts, I was encountering issues with `std::bit_width` not having an appropriate overload for the `xor` between two of them. When `xor`'ing unsigned ints the result is an unsigned int. But when `xor`ing unsigned shorts, the result seems to be a signed int.

```
#include <bit>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned int x = 31;
    unsigned int y = 73;
    std::cout << std::bit_width(x ^ y);
}
```

results in 7

```
#include <bit>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned short x = 31;
    unsigned short y = 73;
    std::cout << std::bit_width(x ^ y);
}
```

Does not compile

> E0304 no instance of function template "std::bit_width" matches the argument list

> 'std::bit_width': no matching overloaded function found

I am using MSVC and Visual Studio 22 on a Windows os.

Obviously I can cast the result explicitly, but I was wondering why this interaction was happening.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#:~:text=m%20%7C%20(n%20%5E%20o)-,Built%2Din%20bitwise%20logic%20operators,-For%20the%20built and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/usual_arithmetic_conversions. TLDR: unsigned short arguments of binary bitwise operators are "promoted" to int...

Comment: Thanks! Looks like all smaller integral types get promoted to int. I did not know that. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Note that on platforms where `sizeof(short) == sizeof(int)`, the `unsigned short` does not get promoted to `int`, it gets promoted to `unsigned int`.